# Angularjs concatenate string with multi-checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to refresh and concatenate a string when multiple checkboxes is checked.

For example, when `'apple'` and `'banana'` are checked, `$scope.strin`g should be `='ab'`, then when `'banana`' is unchecked, `$scope.string` should be left with `'a'`.

What I did does concatenate, however $scope.string won't remove old values, it is still `='aba'`

Here is my attempt on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3ruexuv/).

You can see when all checkboxes are checked it gives me `aababcabcd`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated your code: http://jsfiddle.net/d3ruexuv/1/

The text isn't clearing because you were only appending the items to the current value, not creating a new string altogether. You can see now that an empty string is always created first:

```
var newText = "";
```

and selected items concatenated to that

Comment: How can I get **newText** outside $watch?

Answer (score 2):

You need to refresh the $scope.text property every time the $scope.watch triggers

```
$scope.$watch('items', function() {

    $scope.text = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if($scope.items[i].selected === true){
            $scope.text += $scope.items[i].prefix;
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `$scope.text = "";` before your loop.

Here is a [fixed code](http://jsfiddle.net/xefusea5/):

```
$scope.text = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if($scope.items[i].selected === true){
            $scope.text += $scope.items[i].prefix;
        }
    }
```

This is happening because you only `+=` to the string, which means it will only grow. You never reset it back to `""` (empty string).
If you would do it before each update then the results will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you have += in your loop, but you're not clearing it prior to entering the loop.  Clear the variable before the loop and you're all set.